# Modified winnt.h

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I accidently changed this file in visual studio 2010

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winnt.h
```

I modified arround here:

```
1082 extern "C++" // templates cannot be declared to have 'C' linkage
1083 template <typedef T, size_t N>
1084 char (*RtlpNumberOf( UNALIGNED T (&)[N] ))[N];
1085
1086 #define RTL_NUMBER_OF_V2(A) (sizeof(*RtlpNumberOf(A)))
```

If anyone has the same version of this file, could you please send me the good code for this section?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just found the source somewhere else. The problem is

```
template <typedef T, size_t N>
```

should be template

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
```